# LibreOffice introducing random page breaks

Tags: libreoffice

I normally use LaTeX, but currently I'm collaborating with a couple of people who don't, so I'm forced to use LibreOffice (v. 3.5.7.2 running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). I'm saving the file as .docx so that it goes well with my colleagues' Windows machines, but this seems to create problems with my Linux machine. Specifically, closing and reopening the file causes several page breaks to appear randomly through the document. I can save a 28-page document in the evening, and when I open it again in the morning it has blown up to anywhere between 40 and 50 because of those page breaks. The long term solution, obviously, is to refuse to collaborate with someone that doesn't want to use TeX (or at least Markdown or something that is just plain ASCII). For the very short term, I just need to understand why LibreOffice insists on inserting these page breaks and how to stop it from doing so.

[minor rant: in the past, I worked with a Windows machine and would use Word for collaborations like this. Say what you want about Microsoft and Word, but at least Word was able to keep the document formatting between close-open cycles]

Comment: maybe i'm lucky but i never had such big problems with libreoffice and docx! (although it's far away from a smooth exchange!) - maybe using doc as "lowest common denominator" will work better!

Comment: by the way: if their Microsoft Office reads docx-files, they also can read odt-files (since [MSOffice 2007 SP2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#File_formats_and_metadata))! - so the only way they can only read docx and no odt is when they use MSOffice 2007 SP1; in this case they should anyway update to the newest [SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27838)!!!